# exercise on Gauss divergence theorem- parametrization of the "boundary" surfaces

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

The following is an exercise that was given to me by a friend to help him, on some exercises on multivariable calculus. Though it is a simple application of Gauss divergence theorem, I got rather confused at some points. Below is the original problem, and the some questions I have regarding some notions that we use in the applications of Gauss theorem.

> Let $B \subset \mathbb R^2$ given by
>
> $$ B:= \{ (x,y) : x \in [-1,1], \quad x^2\leq y \} \cap \{ (x,y): x^2 +y^2 \leq 2 \}.$$
>
> and consider the solid given by
>
> $$ V:= \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 : (x,y) \in B, \quad 0 \leq z \leq y \} .$$
>
> Compute the line integral
>
> $$ \int_{ \partial V } (x,y,z) \cdot d(x,y,z).$$

As a first step we should find appropriate parametrizations for the surfaces that enclose the solid, namely for the "top" and the "bottom".

$ \bullet \quad $ The "bottom" $ S_1 = \{ (x,y,0) : (x,y) \in B \}$ is parametrized by the map $ \phi(u,v) := (-u,v,0) ,$ so that $S_1 = \phi(B).$ The normal of the surface is then given by

$$ N_1 = \frac{\partial \phi}{ \partial u} \times \frac{ \partial \phi }{ \partial v}  = (0,0,-1) .$$

$ \bullet \quad $ The "top" $S_2 = \{ (x,y,y) : (x,y) \in B \}$ is parametrized by $ \psi(u,v) = (u,v,v),$ and has normal vector $ N_2= (0,1,1) .$

From the above we conclude that the divergence theorem can be applied and gives, that the original integral is equal to

$$ \int_B \int_0^y 1 \text d z \text d x \text d y = \int_B y \text d x \text d y = \cdots .$$

I have no trouble in computing the last double integral, so I leave like this.

My questions while I was doing the above, are the following.

1. Are the above correct ?
2. I chose the map $ \phi $ so that the normal points "out". Could I have chosen $ \phi(u,v)=(u,v,0),$ and just say that I pick as normal the opposite of the normal of this surface?
3. How could I compute the original surface integral by definition without using the divergence theorem ? Namely, how could I find a parametrization of the $ \partial V $ ? And in this case, how does the outer normal looks like ?
4. Finally, is there any online, free, software that I could use to have an idea of how this picture looks like in the $3$-dimensional space ?

Thank you in advnce.

edit: More details of the problem added and tried to clarify my questions. I apologize for the silly question regardging the normal of a surface given by a graph. I missed a minus in the determinant.

Comment: The normals are ok. You need to calculate the normal for the side.

Comment: @RafaBudría: Thank you for your reply. What do you mean by normal for the side?

Comment: I meant $V$ is limited by three surfaces, the plane $xy$, the slanted plane and the cylinder having as base $B$. Further, I think the correct normal for the second question is the first. You can write the calculations for the second to check the error.

Comment: @RafaBudría: I edit my question. I suppose you mean to find the normal of the surface $ \partial V, $ right ? I am a little confused with this, so I could give some more details/hints it would be great. As for the other question, the thing is i compute the exterior product and cannot where I am wrong.

Comment: @RafaBudría: You are right abou the normal. I missed a minus like always....i really apologize for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering with not special order.

I am using GeoGebra, that online it's handy.

Of course you can evaluate the flux applying the divergence theorem. The integral for the divergence is not correct.

You have $F(x,y,z)=(x,y,z)$, so $\nabla\cdot F=1+1+1=3$. The integral is for the region you stated:

$$\int_V\nabla\cdot Fdv=\int_B\int_0^y 3dzdxdy$$

For the calculation of the flux, we have to consider four surfaces. You calculated the normal vector for two of them. The other two form a cylinder the base of wich is limited by an arc of parabola (values $0\leq y\leq 1$) and an arc of circle (values $1\leq y\leq\sqrt{2}$) intersecting at $(1,1,0)$ and $(-1,1,0)$

For the circular surface of the cylinder: $\alpha_1(u,v)=(\sqrt{2}\cos u,\sqrt{2}\sin u,v)$, ranging $0\leq v\leq\sqrt{2}\sin u$ and $-\pi/4\leq u\leq\pi/4$

$N_3 = \dfrac{\partial \alpha_1}{ \partial u} \times \dfrac{ \partial \alpha_1}{ \partial v}=(\sqrt{2}\cos u,\sqrt{2}\sin u,0)$

For the parabolic one: $\alpha_2(u,v)=(u,u^2,v)$ Ranging $0\leq v\leq u^2$ and $-1\leq u\leq 1$

$N_4 = \dfrac{\partial \alpha_2}{ \partial u} \times \dfrac{ \partial \alpha_2}{ \partial v}=(2u,-1,0)$

You ask to compute the normals in any way and then choose the sign for it in order to be outwards. It's ok.

You have now to compute the four surface integrals

Comment: Dear Rafa, thank you very much for your time. It was long time ago since I saw exercises on these topic and I was mainly confused with the theoretical part, rather than the computations itself.

Comment: You had almost it all :) With respect to the orientation of the normal vectors, I usually check the relative orientation of the tangent vectors in some point where they are easily visualized, then I use the corkscrew rule in any order to see where their cross product points, if the desired one, ok, else, change the order.